# Springboot to store logs in h2-DB: Logback configuration error detected

Tags: spring-boot, logging, h2, logback

I am trying to implement a `POC` which stores logs in Database(H2-Db) using Springboot. I have gone through some documents and finally I found a site with suitable details(https://medium.com/@chakrar27/storing-log-data-in-postgresql-using-logback-db-appender-292891a9918). I followed steps mentioned in that link but I am getting `Logback configuration error detected` error message. Below is complete error information.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@1:66 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[appender]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:62 - no applicable action for [connectionSource], current ElementPath  is [[appender][connectionSource]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:14 - no applicable action for [driverClass], current ElementPath  is [[appender][connectionSource][driverClass]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:6 - no applicable action for [url], current ElementPath  is [[appender][connectionSource][url]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:7 - no applicable action for [user], current ElementPath  is [[appender][connectionSource][user]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@7:11 - no applicable action for [password], current ElementPath  is [[appender][connectionSource][password]]
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:222)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at com.springboot.log.db.SpringbootLogDbApplication.main(SpringbootLogDbApplication.java:10)
```

Below is my code-snippet:

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <driverClass>org.h2.Driver</driverClass>
        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:testdb</url>
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# create database schema from SQL files
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.springboot.log.db</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-log-db</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springboot-log-db</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by updating the logback.xml file and by creating table in H2-DB

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
        <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
            <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
                <driverClass>org.h2.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:h2:mem:testdb</url>
                <user>sa</user>
                <password>password</password> <!-- no password -->
            </connectionSource>
        </appender>

<!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default. -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Table in H2-DB:

```
CREATE TABLE logging_event (
timestmp BIGINT NOT NULL,
formatted_message LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL,
logger_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
level_string VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
thread_name VARCHAR(256),
reference_flag SMALLINT,
arg0 VARCHAR(256),
arg1 VARCHAR(256),
arg2 VARCHAR(256),
arg3 VARCHAR(256),
caller_filename VARCHAR(256), 
caller_class VARCHAR(256), 
caller_method VARCHAR(256), 
caller_line CHAR(4),
event_id IDENTITY NOT NULL);
```